# Search if date contains the month from list

Tags: javascript

I need help with this script i need to see if my date contains one of these **months**

```
('Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd');
```

For example

- **RIGHT CASE:**

  if date `2015/Bal/01`
- **WRONG CASE:**

  if `2015/Bel/01`,

i have tried doing this:

```
    var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
    if (myString.contains('Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd') >= 0) { 
        alert('Yes');
    } else { 
        alert('No');
    }
```

But that ddnt helpled because everytime it writes Yes. Please help.

Comment: `if (myString.contains('Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd') > 0) {` try this

Comment: otherwise your condition is permanently true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.contains` is not part of JavaScript spec and may not universally supported in all browsers.

Try regular expression instead:

```
var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
if (myString.match(/Sau|Vas|Kov|Bal|Geg|Bir|Lie|Rgp|Rgs|Spa|Lap|Grd/i)) { 
    alert('Yes');
} else { 
    alert('No');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
if (myString.contains(['Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd']) >0) { 
    alert('Yes');
} else { 
    alert('No');
}
```

Try that

Comment: `String.prototype.contains` isn't that ES6? (cf. `String.prototype.includes`)

Comment: Try `indexOf` instead of `contains`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
if (['Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd'].some(month => myString.contains(month))) {
    alert('Yes');
} else { 
    alert('No');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have made a working fiddle, but the alerts are very annoying xD

```
var myString = "Kov";
var monthsArray = ['Sau', 'Vas', 'Kov', 'Bal', 'Geg', 'Bir','Lie', 'Rgp', 'Rgs', 'Spa', 'Lap', 'Grd'];

for (var i = 0; i < monthsArray.length; i++){
  (myString.indexOf(monthsArray[i]) > -1) ? alert("yes") : alert("no");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2c58rssL/